# Calculating partial pressure with 3 equilibrium equations

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

So my friend had sent this question to me some days ago and it seems I still am not able to solve it. I am confused whether the amount of A that dissociates in the first equation would account for the third one and how they inter relate. [image]

The correct answer is 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am confused whether the amount of A that dissociates in the first equation would account for the third one and how they inter relate.

All atoms of A are in the form of $\ce{A2}$ initially. After equilibrium is established, some are in the form of atomic $\ce{A}$, and some are part of $\ce{AB}$ while the rest remain as $\ce{A2}$. If you had a dial you could turn, increasing the dissociation constant of $\ce{A2}$ (leaving everything else constant), you would lower the concentration of the $\ce{A2}$, which would disturb the equilibrium of the third reaction, consequently lowering the concentration of $\ce{AB}$ (and increasing that of $\ce{B2}$. So it is all linked, and you have to solve the entire set of equations simultaneously.

**Solution**

It is possible to calculate all five partial pressures using the mass balance of A and B (two equations) and the third equilibrium constant (one equation) together with the given partial pressure of AB and the total pressure (two equations). Initially, the partial pressure of $\ce{A2}$ was 1 atm (same for $\ce{B2}$).

Let $x$ be the partial pressure of $\ce{A2}$ and $y$ the partial pressure of $\ce{B2}$ at equilibrium. From the stoichiometry of reactants and products, we get the following expressions of the partial pressure of A and B (2 atm is the partial pressure if all of A were present in atomic form, starting with 1 atm of $\ce{A2}$):

$$P_A = \pu{2 atm} - P_{AB} - 2x = \pu{1.5 atm} - 2x$$
$$P_B = \pu{2 atm} - P_{AB} - 2y = \pu{1.5 atm} - 2y$$

All five species together have to account for the equilibrium pressure:

$$ x + y + P_A + P_B + P_{AB} = \pu{2.75 atm}$$

Substituting the expressions for $P_A$ and $P_B$, we get:

$$x + y + (\pu{1.5 atm} - 2x) + (\pu{1.5 atm} - 2y) + \pu{0.5 atm} = \pu{2.75 atm}$$

Simplifying, we get:

$$x + y  = \pu{0.75 atm}\tag{*}$$

We can express $y$ by (using the equilibrium constant for the third reaction):

$$ y = \frac{\pu{0.125 atm^2}}{x}$$

and use that in equation (*), simplifying to this quadratic:

$$ x^2 + \pu{0.125 atm^2} = \pu{0.75 atm} \cdot x$$

The two solutions for $x$ are $\pu{0.5 atm}$ and $\pu{0.25 atm}$, where corresponding values for $y$ are $\pu{0.25 atm}$ and $\pu{0.5 atm}$. The two solutions reflect the symmetry of the problem (A and B are interchangeable without changing anything). From this, you can calculate partial pressures of A and B, and the equilibrium constants. Their ratio is 8 for one solution and 1/8 for the other. The last sentence in the problem breaks the symmetry, and the answer is 8, as stated.

This was a brute force answer - I'm sure there is a more elegant approach.

Comment: I understood the question, all thanks to you sir but I would like to ask a few certain doubts. I still did not get how you wrote the equation for the partial pressure of A and B *the 1st equation*. Could you elaborate a little more on that? also i'd give you all my upvotes but my votes don't count at the moment...

Comment: @theRock If all $\ce{A2}$ would dissociate and no AB forms, the partial pressure would be 2 atm. However, there is 0.5 atm of AB, so we have to subtract that. And there is $x$ of $\ce{A2}$ left over, so we have to subtract $2x$ (factor two because of the 2:1 stoichiometry of $\ce{A2 <=> 2A}$).

Comment: Finally got it! Thank you so much sir you are a saviour!